# Why does not appear on these articles everywhere?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have this page:

[link](http://www.dg-design.ch/blog/)

Each article must appear time was made.On the first page it`s ok.From page 2 onwards don`t display the article data.

**CODE PHP:**

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ){ ?>
        <li class="block first-post">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="fancybox-iframe"><?php the_post_thumbnail('vantage-grid-loop'); ?></a>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="fancybox-iframe"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><br>
            <p class="italic"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo substr(get_the_content(),0,600).'...'; ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php } else if( $wp_query->current_post > 0 && $wp_query->current_post < 5 ) { ?>
        <li class="block">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="fancybox-iframe"><?php the_post_thumbnail('blog'); ?></a>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="fancybox-iframe"><?php echo substr(get_the_title(),0,20).'...'; ?></a></h3><br>
            <p class="italic"> <?php the_date(); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo substr(get_the_content(),0,70).'...'; ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="block">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="fancybox-iframe"><?php the_post_thumbnail('blog'); ?></a>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="fancybox-iframe"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><br>

            //is displayed here date 
            <p class="italic"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo substr(get_the_content(),0,600).'...'; ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php //get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.italic{font-style:italic;cursor:pointer;}
```

I put a picture to see how the code is on the front page and it is on the second page.
http://i60.tinypic.com/2dcd6rt.jpg

You can help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are no value passing to this `<p><?php echo substr(get_the_content(),0,70).'...'; ?></p>`

Comment: and how can I solve this?

Comment: what you trying to cheek on that??